# Decorator Pattern issue in JAVA

Tags: java, int, double, decorator

i have - Worker **interface**.
each worker has energy.

```
public interface Worker {
    int work();
    double getEnergy();
}
```

and - juniorWorker class that **implements** Worker **interface**.
junior worker has 100 energy.

```
public class juniorWorker implements Worker {
    public int work() {
        return (int) getEnergy();
    }
    public double getEnergy() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

and also have - efficientWork, powerWork classes that **implements** Worker **interface**.
efficientWork will reduce energy by 20%.
powerWork will raise energy by 10%.

```
public class efficientWork implements Worker {
    private Worker worker;
    public efficientWork(Worker w) {
        this.worker=w;
}
    public int work() {
        return (int) (worker.getEnergy()*getEnergy());
    }
    public double getEnergy() {
        return 0.8;
    }
}
public class PowerWork implements Worker {
    private Worker worker;
    public PowerWork(Worker w) {
        this.worker=w;
}
    public int work() {
        return  (int) (worker.getEnergy()*getEnergy());
    }
    public double getEnergy() {
        return 1.1;
    }
}
```

Actually, i am trying **int work()** will sum up the total **energy** each worker will spend.
for example, my Demo class:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker j= new efficientWork(new juniorWorker());
        System.out.println(j.work());
    }
}
```

this case **IS WORKING** - system will print **80**.

**But this example, printing 0 always :**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker j= new efficientWork(new PowerWork(new juniorWorker()));
        System.out.println(j.work());
    }
}
```

Help ? i am expecting to get 88! (110*0.8)

Comment: Why are you passing a worker object to all the classes implementing worker ?

Comment: i am expecting to get 88! (110*0.8)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels just explained some more.

Comment: Just step through the `work`-methods of `efficientWorker` and `PowerWork` with a debugger and you'll see where the mistake lies immediately. And in general: work on your naming-habits. These names are far from what "good" names in Java look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling the `work()` not the `getEnergy()` method on the enclosed worker object held within the decorator within its `work()` method.

```
// decorator's work method
public int work() {
    // return (int) (worker.getEnergy() * getEnergy()); // NO!
    return (int) (worker.work() * getEnergy());    // YES!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the call heirarchy.
`efficientWork.work()` calls `worker.getEnergy()`, with a `PowerWork` as `worker`.  `PowerWork.getEnergy()` returns 1.1.

1.1 * 0.8 = 0.88, which is then cast to an int and becomes 0.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `efficientworker.work()` logically expands to

```
(int)(efficientWork.getEnergy() * PowerWork.getEnergy()) 
= (int)(0.8 * 1.1) 
= (int)(0.88)
= 0
```